# How to set a particular style to the first element in a CollectionView in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I was seeing Metro style apps, and I realized that the XAML style in the first element of a CollectionView has a different styles from the anothers.

Check this example.

[image]

I just one to know how to set a different style for the first element in XAML? I was thinking, should I need to implement converter to do this? Or create template?

Comment: I don't believe that is using the `VariableSizeWrapGrid` from the default `GroupedItemsPage` template (Notice the 'see more' item at the end). IMHO, its just a grid with a RowSpan/ColumnSpan for the first item.

Comment: Ohh I see, one doubt Ritch. So, how can I stablish the rest of the items in the grid?

Comment: I believe the grid to be a fixed size, but you could just add a `VariableSizeWrapGrid` with a column span and row span of the correct amount. Your model code would have to provide the correct filtering on the collection to make it work. Either way, I doubt that this is a stock template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this as a template bound to a custom object that exposes various properties for databinding (or ViewModels, whatever floats your WinRT boat)

[image]

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" Text="First" FontSize="288"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Second" FontSize="70"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="Third" FontSize="70"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Text="Fourth" FontSize="70"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="Blah" FontSize="70"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Text="Blah" FontSize="70"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Text="Blah" FontSize="70"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Text="Blah" FontSize="70"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Text="Blah" FontSize="70"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Text="Blah" FontSize="70"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Text="Blah" FontSize="70"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="4">
                <Run FontSize="70">Moar</Run>
                <LineBreak/>
                <Run FontSize="20">Ommm nom nom</Run>
                <LineBreak/>
                <Run FontSize="10">blah blah blah</Run>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```